# no match for operator == or != in my code within the do while loop

Tags: c++, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

within the DO-WHILE loop the == and != operators have "no match"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string password = "gang";

    int input;
    cin >> input;


    do{

        cout<<"Enter password here:   "<<endl;

        if(input == password){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Password incorrect"<<endl;
        }

    }
    while(input != password);
    cout<<"Password correct"<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\New User\Desktop\c++\666666666666658uttu\main.cpp|18|error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'int' and 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}')|
```

Comment: You can't compare an `int` to a `std::string`

Comment: What is the type of the variable `password`? What is the type of the variable `input`? Can those two types be compared?

Comment: Yes, according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), there is no overloaded `operator==`, or `operator!=`, that takes `int`, and `std::string`. What are you confused about?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are comparing a string with a int

Comment: We've all been there before. Just try reading the error message in a bit more detail next time.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the input in as an int, but comparing it to a string.

Do this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string password = "gang";

    string input; // <<<<<<HERE
    cin >> input; 


    do{

        cout<<"Enter password here:   "<<endl;

        if(input == password){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Password incorrect"<<endl;
        }

    }
    while(input != password);
    cout<<"Password correct"<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The program in any case is wrong.:)

The variable `input` is declared as having the type `int`.

```
int input;
```

Then you are trying to compare the entered integer with an object having the type `std::string`.

```
string password = "gang";
// ...
if(input == password){
```

Moreover the loop is infinite because the variable `input` even if it was declared as having the type `std::string` is not changed within the loop.

Also you should include header `<string>`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string password = "gang";
    std::string input;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter password here: ";

        if ( not ( std::cin >> input ) or ( input != password ) )
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Password incorrect\n";
        }
    } while ( input != password );

    std::cout << "Password correct" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```